# Cannot access a method in other class, but other one can

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a class with 2 methods, but when I'm debugging I can access  `showLog()`  method but cannot access `editProductCode()` method from other class.
This is my code:

```
class ProductCodeModel(private val mView: ProductCodeContract.View) : ProductCodeContract.Model {

fun showLog(){
    Log.e("====", "Can access this method")
}

override fun editProductCode(storeId: Int?, departmentId: Int?, name: String?, code: String?, unit: String?, isDynamicReference: Int?, minimumLimit: Float?, isActive: Int?, note: String?) {
    Constraint.mRetrofit?.create(MaterialService::class.java)
            ?.editProductCode(storeId, departmentId, name, code, unit, minimumLimit, isDynamicReference, isActive, note)
            ?.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            ?.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            ?.subscribeWith(object : DisposableObserver<InventoryResponse>() {
                override fun onComplete() {

                }

                override fun onNext(response: InventoryResponse) {
                    if (response.status == Constraint.STATUS_RIGHT)
                        mView.editProductCodeSuccess(response.inventory)
                    else {
                        mView.editProductCodeFailed(response.error?.desc)
                    }
                }

                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                    val msg = Resources.getSystem().getString(android.R.string.unknownName)
                    mView.editProductCodeFailed(msg)
                }
            })
}
```

This is my declaration:

```
private val mModel = ProductCodeModel(this)
mModel.showLog() //I can access this method
mModel.editProductCode(storeId, departmentId, name, code, unit, isDynamicReference, minimumLimit, isActive, note) //I cannot access this method
```

**ProductCodeContract class**

```
interface ProductCodeContract {

interface View {
    fun getInventoryListSuccess(inventoryList: List<Inventory>?)
    fun getInventoryListFailed(msg: String?)

    fun createProductCodeSuccess(inventory: Inventory?)
    fun createProductCodeFailed(msg: String?)

    fun editProductCodeSuccess(inventory: Inventory?)
    fun editProductCodeFailed(msg: String?)
}

interface Model {
    fun getInventoryList(storeId: Int?, offset: Int?, limit: Int?)
    fun createProductCode(storeId: Int?, departmentId: Int?, name: String?, code: String?, unit: String?, isDynamicReference: Int?,
                          minimumLimit: Float?, isActive: Int?, note: String?)

    fun editProductCode(storeId: Int?, departmentId: Int?, name: String?, code: String?, unit: String?, isDynamicReference: Int?,
                        minimumLimit: Float?, isActive: Int?, note: String?)
}
```

}

Somebody help me...

Comment: Can you share your `ProductCodeContract.Model` class?

Comment: I mean the code of ProductCodeContract.Model?

Comment: @Varundroid updated my question

Comment: Can you make your model open and try again?

Comment: What’s the actual error/exception?

Comment: @Strelok Actual error is **Constraint.mRetrofit** is **null** but I didn't see it

Comment: Well, looks like you have your answer. Need to investigate why that property is null.

Comment: @Strelok thanks guy

Answer (score 0):

Try import nested interface method.